# How to load website and debug node application?

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am unable to figure out how to get to my landing page while running `node --inspect app.js`? For example, when I run it locally I would normally go to localhost:3000.

It is not exactly clear to me how to get both going. My output with node is as follows:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\app>node  --inspect app.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/1e900a59-bd94-486c-9eee-
d3be90717377
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
// more output
```

After I get the Devtools running using NiM, where do I go from there?

Thank you,

Comment: is your site served by your node app.js? Or is it totally separate?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you're asking on how to open your node debugger.
But anyway, if you have chrome installed, you can follow this step to open your chrome debugger:

1. Open up chrome and go to `chrome://inspect`
2. Click open dedicated devtools for node
   [image]
3. If you have your node running with `--inspect` flag, you'll be able to see the logs under `console` tab and also browse through your source under `Sources` tab
   [image]

Comment: hey, your comment was actually what was wrong. It worked after running `node --inspect ./bin/www` and instead of `app.js` I got it working.